# Approach to solve ceiling identities

Tags: discrete-mathematics, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Other than *trial and error*, is there a way to solve the following problem

Show that the smallest integer value of $N$ for which

$$\left\lceil\frac{N}{4}\right\rceil = 7$$ is 25

I am not able to find a way to proceed given the identities I know like:
$$\left\lceil\ -x \right\rceil = -\left\lfloor\ x\right\rfloor$$
and
$$\left\lceil\ x + n \right\rceil = \left\lceil\ x\right\rceil + n$$

Comment: It might be helpful to note that $\lceil x \rceil = y$ implies that $y-1 < x \le y$.  That being said, I can think of values of $N$ smaller than $25$ which satisfy that equation... (unless you are not telling us something about $N$? like it must be an integer?).

Comment: @XanderHenderson yes N is an integer.  Sorry I missed that out in my original post.  I have updated my post.